# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined window location

Tags: javascript

I have this error and I google about it. But I didn´t found my issue

```
  var url = window.location.hash.split('?Token=')[1];
        url = url.split('Token=');

        function cambiarContrasena(usuario, completado, fallo) {
            apiService.post('/api/usuario/cambiarContrasena?token='+url, usuario,
            completado,
            fallo);
        }
```

My value isn´t empty or undefinied, can anyone help me there? Thanks!

Comment: Please show the value of `console.log(window.location.hash);`

Comment: It´s `#/cambiarContrasena.html?Token=e12009cf-d48d-42e7-ba43-83b5082019bb` @4castle

Comment: You're sure the error isn't from the second line

Comment: error is in the second line `url = url.split('Token=');`, chrome console show me it @adeneo

Comment: Please create a minimal test case. If I set `window.location.hash` to the supplied string I can't reproduce the problem. The second line has gone one step too far - ithere is no `Token=` remaining in `url` after the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `href` instead of `hash`.

```
 var url = window.location.href.split('?Token=')[1];
 // url = url.split('Token='); no need to split it again.

 function cambiarContrasena(usuario, completado, fallo) {
        apiService.post('/api/usuario/cambiarContrasena?token='+url, usuario,
        completado,
        fallo);
 }
```

Difference between `hash` and `href` is they return different part of URL. Here is the anatomy of URL:

[image: Anatomy of a URL]
<sub>(source: [doepud.co.uk](https://doepud.co.uk/images/blogs/complex_url.png))</sub>

In this case `window.location.hash` returns `#00h02m30s` where `windows.location.href` returns entire URL.

Comment: same issue Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Comment: Show us console.log(location.href)

Comment: http://localhost:55718/Cliente/ and should be http://localhost:55718/Cliente/#/login.html

Comment: In your second line you try to split it again. It causes the error.

Comment: Can you explain me why I should use href instead hash?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `var url = window.location.split('?Token=')[1];` (no `.hash` since you want to take parameter)

Comment: If I don´t use hash I get Uncaught TypeError: window.location.split is not a function

Comment: My mistake, should be `.href`, see @Nobody 's answer.